# Natsort foreach data from folder into a select

Tags: php, select, foreach

I am trying to sort files from a folder where the names is numbers.
I have been trying to fix this problem for a long time but I haven't found a solution that actually works.

It's sorting 
1
10
11
2
20
Etc.

I am trying to get it to do a natural sorting.
1
2
3
4
5
6

```
<?php 
    foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/4-2-baggrund-gentag-gradient-filer/*') as $filenameselsyvogfyrre){
    $filenameselsyvogfyrre = basename($filenameselsyvogfyrre);
    $filenameselotteogfyrre = pathinfo($filenameselsyvogfyrre, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // returns 'filename'
    echo "<option class='formstyle' value='" . $filenameselotteogfyrre . "'>".$filenameselotteogfyrre."</option>";}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function.

First you get all items as array, then sort'em and then do `foreach`:

```
$files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/4-2-baggrund-gentag-gradient-filer/*');
natsort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file . PHP_EOL;
}
```